# qwt: plot 1-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, qt, plot, qwt

What is the most simple way to plot a 1-dimensional array like that:

```
double ad_data[64];
int i;
for(i=0; i<64; i++)
{
    ad_data[i] = sin( 1.0/16 * i * 3.1415 );
}
```

in qwt?

Answer (score 0):

That's THE universal and easiest (and maybe the only) way to do it. The difficulty is in changing the elements of the array and the difficulty depends on that what does the program does. So you can't make this any easier than that.